# Why does a function passed to a directive not update a scope variable?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

In this AngularJS code:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/xfbgjun5/8/

I have a scope function `addCustomer()` which will not update the scope variable `score`:

```
.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = ['First','Second','Third'];
    $scope.score = 'sdfkj';
    $scope.addCustomer = function() {
        $scope.score = 'this does not work';
        console.log('but it obviously gets here');
    }
    $scope.changeIt = function() {
        $scope.score = 'this works';
    }
    ...
})
```

I pass in the function `addCustomer()` as `add`:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        datasource: '=',
        add: '&'
    },
    link: link
};
```

and then call it in my directive:

```
function addItem() {
    scope.add();
    items.push('new customer');
    render();
}
```

**Why doesn't the scope function `addCustomer()` update the scope variable `score`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your fiddle your issue is here:

```
element.on('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.id === 'addItem') {
        addItem();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

By doing an element.on you're wiring up your own event in angular. This won't work and you need to do this as well:

```
element.on('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.id === 'addItem') {
        addItem();
        event.preventDefault();
        scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

This is because the 'click' happenned outside of angular if you build it this way. You should also look into how to build a directive as this is not how you build it (with an html variable and then adding it in). There shouldn't be any html (expect in specific circumstances) in your directive code.